# Python| Github opening file

Tags: python, git, github

Всем привет, как на пайтоне запустить онлайн файл залитый на github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто скачай репозиторий (там кнопка есть для загрузки) себе на комп, и если это полноценная библиотека, то на странице репозитория есть инструкция по установке, которая обычно производится через файл setup.py:
python setup.py install (команда вводится в командной оболочке и внутри каталога в котором этом файл находится).
Еще можно это делать прямо через pip, ничего не скачивая вручную, но для этого в системе должне быть установлен git:
pip install git+https://github.com/название_репозитория.

Если же в репозитории лежит просто набор скриптов, то найди главный файл и запусти его, например, в командной оболочке системы: python main.py.